# Firebase, is there anything better than a cloud scheduler?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

When some information is stored in the firestore, each document is storing some specific time in the future, and according to that time, the event should occur in the user's app.

The first way I could find was the Cloud Function pub sub scheduler. However, I could not use this because the time is fixed.

The second method was to use Cloud Function + Cloud Task. I have referenced this. https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a

This perfectly performed the function I really wanted, but there was a fatal drawback in the Cloud Task, because I could only save the event within 30 days. In other words, future time exceeding 30 days did not apply to this.

I want this event to be saved over the long term. And I want it to be somewhat smooth for large traffic.

I`m using Flutter/Firebase, how to implement this requirements above?

thank you for reading happy new year

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not a satisfying answer, but my previous company had similar challenges, and we ended up going with using Cloud Function pub sub scheduler to invoke function every minute. Basically we invoked cloud function every minute and see if there are unprocessed queues. I wish if there were a better way of scheduling a function in the future, but I believe this is as good as it gets as of right now.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. If there is no other than this method after a certain period, I will adopt this.

Comment: @rounpaleum You can replace pub-sub with a third-party cron job service (like cron-job.org) that will use RTDB REST API POST requests to write at a path that will trigger your cloud function. Write `{'.sv': 'timestamp'}` so you can use the `now` variable in rules to prevent hackers from spam-triggering your function.